# CSS optimization : Select element once and then apply corresponding classes

Tags: css

I have a css code looking like this :

```
#myid .firstdiv {display:none}
#myid .seconddiv {color:red}
#myid .thirddiv {color:yellow}
#myid .fourthdiv {color:blue}
```

Is there a way to select #myid just once and then apply the corresponding classes, to make the code lighter? Like :

```
#myid {
    .firstdiv {display:none}
    .seconddiv {color:red}
    .thirddiv {color:yellow}
    .fourthdiv {color:blue}
}
```

If yes, are there any drawbacks?

Comment: Yeah there is, it's called [sass](https://sass-lang.com).

Comment: Besides being non-compliant with CSS syntax? None I'd say. But that's exactly how the majority of CSS preprocessors handle this.

Comment: @yousoumar is right, check this [example](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/jOZGLZR)

Comment: Oh perfect! So i had the right syntax, but thought it wasn't correct because notepad++ doesn't seem to recognize it so i didn't even test it. Thank you! 

Do you know if it improves performance, even slightly?